# Difficulties adding a new blank line every 10 lines of text in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a python script that will format books that I input from the internet for school.

Currently both section one and section three are functional. The book is able to have all blank lines removed, and it is outputted into a plain text file.

The issue I'm having is with section two. After all of the blank lines have been removed, every 10 lines there should be a new blank line re inserted into the text file.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import sys
#setting finalBook as a string
finalBook = ""
i = int(0)

#section one
#removing all original blank lines from book
with open("dangerousGame.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.isspace():
            finalBook = finalBook + line

#section two
#add in a blank line every 10 lines
for i in finalBook:
    if i % 10 == 0 and i != 0: 
        finalBook = finalBook + "\n"

#section three
#output in a plain text             
with open("test.txt", "w") as x:
        x.write(finalBook)
```

So far I have tried searching for '\n' but it seems as though Python thinks that every line has one which is not the case. I also attempted tried splitting the book into a list and formatting it that way but this also did not work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want an empty line after every 10 lines of text, or after every 9 lines of text (i.e. the 10th line would be empty)?

Comment: After every 10 lines of text - the 10th line being empty

Comment: See the solution below, that serves for any number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for i in finalBook:
    if i % 10 == 0 and i != 0: 
        finalBook = finalBook + "\n"
```

You will want something like:

```
n = 10
finalBook = [
    line for block in (
        finalBook[i:i + n] + ['\n'] for i in range(0, len(finalBook), n)
    ) for line in block
]
```

For example:

```
finalBook = [str(i) + '\n' for i in range(10)]

n = 3
finalBook = [
    line for block in (
        finalBook[i:i + n] + ['\n'] for i in range(0, len(finalBook), n)
    ) for line in block
]

print(finalBook)
```

Output:

```
['0\n', '1\n', '2\n', '\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '\n', '6\n', '7\n', '8\n', '\n', '9\n', '\n']
```

By the way, for your code to be more Pythonic, consider renaming `finalBook` to `final_book`, since 'snake-case' is the recommended naming convention for Python.